# Bayesian inverse problems on non-separable Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, st.statistics, banach-spaces, bayesian-probability, inverse-problems

I am now studying Bayesian inverse problems. In the note of Dashti and Stuart https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.6989, they mentioned that "... when considering a non-separable Banach space $B$, it is not clear what the ''natural" $\sigma$-algebra on $B$ is ...", where the usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra are considered.

My questions are:

1. What is the intuition behind the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra? (More precisely, why do we need this $\sigma$-algebra?)
2. Why do we need them to coincide (as in the case $B$ is a separable Banach space)? Is it a problem if we just consider the usual $\sigma$-algebra on a Banach space $B$ to study Bayesian inverse problems?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand\B{\mathscr B}\newcommand\C{\mathscr C}$There is hardly any particular intuition behind the concept of the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra. This is just the smallest $\sigma$-algebra with respect to which all continuous linear functionals (which are arguably the simplest functionals) are measurable.

So, the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra (say $\C$) appears to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra of natural interest. It is therefore great to have a situation when this smallest $\sigma$-algebra is already big enough to coincide with the bigger Borel $\sigma$-algebra (say $\B$) generated by the strong topology; in particular, this happens when the Banach space $B$ is separable.

However, $\C$ may be strictly smaller than $\B$; see e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4176812/96609).

It may be easier to first define a probability measure on the smallest $\sigma$-algebra of interest, $\C$ -- this can be done just via (the [characteristic functional](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22characteristic%20functional%22&sxsrf=APq-WBv6M_gg76cym7wtHw1wamZNjjna3g%3A1643322723444&ei=Yx3zYYXTGvSvptQP-cqE8Ac&ved=0ahUKEwjFkLqZ_tL1AhX0l4kEHXklAX4Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22characteristic%20functional%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgUIABCABDIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIICAAQBxAKEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgQIABAeOgcIABBHELADOgYIABAWEB46CAgAEBYQChAeSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUMsVWLo0YOU3aAJwAngAgAFyiAHHApIBAzAuM5gBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) and) the [Kolmogorov extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem). (In the usual setting of the Kolmogorov extension theorem, the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra is naturally generated by the so-called "finite-dimensional" measurable sets.)

More work will then be needed to extend the probability measure from $\C$ to $\B$ -- so that one be able to define, in particular, the probability measure of balls.